# Cannot read property 'toLowerCase'

Tags: javascript

I am receiving the following error:
cannot read property 'toLowerCase'

with the following code:

```
(function() {
    var tags = document.getElementsByTagName("h3"), l = tags.length, i, newid, n;
    for( i=0; i<l; i++) {
        newid = tags[i].firstChild.nodeValue.toLowerCase().replace(/[^a-z0-9-]/g,'-').replace(/--+/g,'-');
        if( document.getElementById(newid)) {
            n = 1;
            do {n++;}
            while(document.getElementById(newid+'-'+n));
            newid += '-'+n;
        }
        tags[i].id = newid;
    }
})();
```

Any ideas?

Comment: That's not the full error. And what's `nodeValue` returning?

Comment: I am guessing `tags[i].firstChild.nodeValue` is undefined or not a string.

Comment: `.nodeValue` is for text nodes and comments. You're asking about DOM selection without showing the DOM, so that's not helpful...

Comment: You probably want `tags[i].firstChild.textContent.toLowerCase()`, but again, you didn't give an example of the document, so all we can do is guess.

Comment: You should wrap your item with an if statement to check if the node exists before getting the data.

Comment: Sorry should have included the page URL: https://www.kalimukti.com/blog/how-to-create-an-effective-employee-well-being-strategy-proven-to-boost-productivity which will show you the full code and error in the console

Comment: @simondlh no, you should have included all the relevant information here, not link to off-site resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
newid = tags[i].firstChild.nodeValue.(...);
```

In this case, it is most likely that the Node you are asking the `nodeValue` of is not a Text Node, but an Element Node. The element as well as the text it contains are both `Nodes` (the Text Node being a child of the Element Node).

If you don't plan on getting the Text Node and then retrieve its `nodeValue`, then you'll want to get the `textContent` of the Element Node, which will recursively get the `textContent` from each of its nested children.

```
(function() {
    var tags = document.getElementsByTagName("h3"), l = tags.length, i, newid, n;
    for( i=0; i<l; i++) {
        newid = tags[i].firstChild.textContent.toLowerCase().replace(/[^a-z0-9-]/g,'-').replace(/--+/g,'-');
        if( document.getElementById(newid)) {
            n = 1;
            do {n++;}
            while(document.getElementById(newid+'-'+n));
            newid += '-'+n;
        }
        tags[i].id = newid;
    }
})();
```

Comment: That worked! Thanks for taking the time to help me out everyone

Comment: @simondlh Here's more if you want to know more about the nodeValue attribute: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeValue